# Specific Index Match

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, excel-2007

I have datas in D:I , and I want to do an Index Match in B2.

But I have a problem with it

[image]

For now, my formula is :

```
=INDEX(D1:I7;MATCH(B1;D1:I7;0);MATCH(A2;D2:I2;0))
```

I think my problem comes from the first match :

```
MATCH(B1;D1:I7;0)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MATCH needs one Column or one Row.

Use other INDEX/MATCH to do what you want.

```
=INDEX(INDEX(D:I,0,MATCH(A2,D2:I2,0)),MATCH(B1,INDEX(D:I,0,MATCH(A2,D2:I2,0)-1),0))
```

[image]

Comment: A1 is your formula is A2 ?  it still doesn't work, it mark #N/A

Comment: @babou works for me, make sure you change all the `,` to your `;`

Comment: it works very well !! thank you for this hard Index match, it help me a lot !